# Using latitude and longitude values to plot users location records

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a mobile app that allows a user to record some data about their favourite monuments. Now, when a user takes a photo of their monument the lat and long values are instantly recorded. Giving me two separate values.

The user then syncs this data with my PostGreSQL database. I want to manipulate this data on my website service.

All I want is a simple map plugin which will take each (so like a foreach loop) record relating to a user (name of monument, lat and long) and display it on a map with icon markers.

So for example, you could have a  favourite monument in Cardiff and one in London. You would have two markers displayed on your account map and when you click on their a pop-up says 'Cardiff Museum' and 'London Eye'.

I've tried multiple searches on Google but to no avail.

Has anyone ever implemented something similar? I'm good with either PHP or JQuery or both solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code where you can pass multiple lat-long combinations to add a marker for each user location.

Repeat this code for every marker you need in your loop to traverse locations array.

```
   t.push('Location Name 1');
    x.push(33.84659); // you can write like x.push(<?php echo $userloc[0]['lat']?>)
    y.push(-84.35686);
    h.push('<p><strong>Location Name 1</strong><br/>Address 1</p>');
```

The complete code is given below.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { initialize(); });

    function initialize() {
        var map_options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.84659,-84.35686),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var google_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), map_options);

        var info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'loading'
        });

        var t = [];
        var x = [];
        var y = [];
        var h = [];

        t.push('Location Name 1');
        x.push(33.84659);
        y.push(-84.35686);
        h.push('<p><strong>Location Name 1</strong><br/>Address 1</p>');

        t.push('Location Name 2');
        x.push(33.846253);
        y.push(-84.362125);
        h.push('<p><strong>Location Name 2</strong><br/>Address 2</p>');

        var i = 0;
        for ( item in t ) {
            var m = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:       google_map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title:     t[i],
                position:  new google.maps.LatLng(x[i],y[i]),
                html:      h[i]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function() {
                info_window.setContent(this.html);
                info_window.open(google_map, this);
            });
            i++;
        }
    }
</script> 
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px;height:400px;">Google Map</div>
```

Comment: This link may help you. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays#Markers

Comment: This is more what I am looking for but I can't specify each Location. I need to read in the location data from my PostgreSQL database. Could you suggest an edit to accommodate a php fix for this?

Comment: <?php
// Fetch data from pgsql in locations array
for($i=0;$i<count($locations);$i++)
{
?>

 t.push('<?php echo $locations[$i]['name']; ?>');
    x.push(<?php echo $locations[$i]['lat']?>); // you can write like x.push(<?php echo $locations[$i]['lat']?>)
    y.push(<?php echo $locations[$i]['lat']?>);
    h.push('<p><strong><?php echo $locations[$i]['name']; ?></strong><br/>
  <?php echo $locations[$i]['address']; ?></p>');

<?php
}
?>

Comment: Thanks for the PHP code, could you possibly edit your answer and include it as a part of the answer itself. Difficult really all that in a comment chunk :P thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you. You can see its working demo here(http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php?lat=-33.866603&lon=151.207108&setLatLon=Set)

```
<!-- Original script taken from: http://conversationswithmyself.com/googleMapDemo.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        h1 {
            font-family:sans-serif;
            color:blue;
            text-align: center;
            font-size:120%;
        }

        .tekst {
            font-family:sans-serif;
            color:blue;
            font-size:100%;
        }

        .smalltekst {
            font-family:sans-serif;
            color:black;
            font-size:80%;
        }
        --> 
        </style>
        <style type="text/css">
        v\:* {
            behavior:url(#default#VML);
        }
        </style>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAF4PVqw0p5l92pEmE39k0MRQWxhPw7-SAnMb84NfHs4vQ3HTp4BTb-yeL6fQg7Up9d9idBGy5naXydw" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Google Maps Latitude, Longitude Popup</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Google Maps Latitude, Longitude Popup</h1>
        <div style="width: 600px;" class="tekst"><b>Simply click  on the map on a location and it will provide you with the latitude and longitude in the callout window.</b></div>
        <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
        <div id="geo" style="width: 300px;position: absolute;left: 620px;top: 100px;" class="tekst">
        <form name="setLatLon" action="googleMapLocation.php">
            <b>* Coordinates:</b><br />
            <table>
                <tr><td>* Lat:</td><td><input type='text' name='lat' id="frmLat"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>* Lon:</td><td><input type='text' name='lon' id="frmLon"></td></tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="setLatLon" value="Set"><br />
        </form><br />
        <b>* Flickr tags:</b><br />
        <textarea id="geocode" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea><br />
        <br />
        <b>* RoboGEO tags:</b><br />
        <textarea id="geocodeRoboGEO" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea><br />
        * <a href="#" target="_blank" id="multimap">Show location on Multimap</a><br />
        * <a href="#" id="maplink">Permanent Link</a><br /><br />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        google_ad_client = "pub-1588116269263536";
        google_alternate_color = "FFFFFF";
        google_ad_width = 234;
        google_ad_height = 60;
        google_ad_format = "234x60_as";
        google_ad_type = "text";
        //2006-09-30: Map
        google_ad_channel ="0993881556";
        google_color_border = "DDDDDD";
        google_color_bg = "DDDDDD";
        google_color_link = "0000FF";
        google_color_text = "333333";
        google_color_url = "333333";
        //-->
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 600px;" class="smalltekst">

            <p><i>Address lookup has been removed because it violated the ToS of Google Maps.</i></p>

        Based on code taken from <a href="http://conversationswithmyself.com/googleMapDemo.html">this website</a> and <a href="http://www.evolt.org/article/Javascript_to_Parse_URLs_in_the_Browser/17/14435/?format=print">this website</a>.<br />
All other errors are caused by code written by <a href="http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/">Pierre Gorissen</a>.<br />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var baseLink = "http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php";
    var multimapBaseLink = "http://www.multimap.com/map/browse.cgi?scale=10000&icon=x";
    var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    var setLat = 51.618017;
    var setLon = 2.48291;   

    // argItems code taken from 
    // http://www.evolt.org/article/Javascript_to_Parse_URLs_in_the_Browser/17/14435/?format=print
    function argItems (theArgName) {
        sArgs = location.search.slice(1).split('&');
            r = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < sArgs.length; i++) {
                if (sArgs[i].slice(0,sArgs[i].indexOf('=')) == theArgName) {
                        r = sArgs[i].slice(sArgs[i].indexOf('=')+1);
                        break;
                }
            }
        return (r.length > 0 ? unescape(r).split(',') : '')
    }


    function getCoordForAddress(response) {

        if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
            alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode that address\n\n Sorry, dat adres bestaat blijkbaar niet!");
        } else {
            place = response.Placemark[0];
            setLat = place.Point.coordinates[1];
            setLon = place.Point.coordinates[0];
            setLat = setLat.toFixed(6);
            setLon = setLon.toFixed(6);
            document.getElementById("frmLat").value = setLat;
            document.getElementById("frmLon").value = setLon;
        }
        placeMarker(setLat, setLon)
    }


    function placeMarker(setLat, setLon) {

        var message = "geotagged geo:lat=" + setLat + " geo:lon=" + setLon + " "; 
        document.getElementById("geocode").value = message;
        var messageRoboGEO = setLat + ";" + setLon + ""; 
        document.getElementById("geocodeRoboGEO").value = messageRoboGEO;

        document.getElementById("geocode").focus();
        document.getElementById("geocode").select();

        document.getElementById("maplink").href = baseLink + "?lat=" + setLat + "&lon=" + setLon ;
        document.getElementById("multimap").href = multimapBaseLink + "&lat=" + setLat + "&lon=" + setLon ;
        document.getElementById("frmLat").value = setLat;
        document.getElementById("frmLon").value = setLon;

        var map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map"));

        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl()); // added
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl()); // added
        map.centerAndZoom(new GPoint(setLon, setLat), 12);

        var point = new GPoint(setLon, setLat);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        map.addOverlay(marker);

        GEvent.addListener(map, 'click', function(overlay, point) {
            if (overlay) {
                map.removeOverlay(overlay);
            } else if (point) {
                map.recenterOrPanToLatLng(point);
                var marker = new GMarker(point);
                map.addOverlay(marker);
                var matchll = /\(([-.\d]*), ([-.\d]*)/.exec( point );
                if ( matchll ) { 
                    var lat = parseFloat( matchll[1] );
                    var lon = parseFloat( matchll[2] );
                    lat = lat.toFixed(6);
                    lon = lon.toFixed(6);
                    var message = "geotagged geo:lat=" + lat + " geo:lon=" + lon + " "; 
                    var messageRoboGEO = lat + ";" + lon + ""; 
                } else { 
                    var message = "<b>Error extracting info from</b>:" + point + ""; 
                    var messagRoboGEO = message;
                }

                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(message);
                document.getElementById("geocode").value = message;
                document.getElementById("geocodeRoboGEO").value = messageRoboGEO;
                document.getElementById("geocode").focus();
                document.getElementById("geocode").select();

                document.getElementById("maplink").href = baseLink + "?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon ;
                document.getElementById("multimap").href = multimapBaseLink + "&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon ;
                document.getElementById("frmLat").value = lat;
                document.getElementById("frmLon").value = lon;

            }
        });
    }

    function findAddress() {
        myAddress = document.getElementById("address").value;
        geocoder.getLocations(myAddress, getCoordForAddress);

    }


    if (argItems("lat") == '' || argItems("lon") == '') {
        placeMarker(setLat, setLon);
    } else {
        var setLat = parseFloat( argItems("lat") );
        var setLon = parseFloat( argItems("lon") );
        setLat = setLat.toFixed(6);
        setLon = setLon.toFixed(6);
        placeMarker(setLat, setLon);
    }

    //]]>
    </script>
<!-- Start twatch code -->
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
//<![CDATA[
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="/Pierre/twatch/jslogger.php?ref='+( document["referrer"]==null?'':escape(document.referrer))+'&pg='+escape(window.location)+'&cparams=true"></scr'+'ipt>');
//]]>
//--></script>
<!-- End twatch code -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the implementation is good but not what I want to achieve. I want the markers to be automatically generated based on each lat and lng value related to one users records.

Comment: you mean you need multiple markers in same map to represent each lat-long combination for the users?

Comment: basically a user can capture different locations on their smartphone which are then geo-tagged. For each record they capture, they will have a new lat and lng combination. Say a user has five records, so five pairs of lat lng values, they will have 5 markers on the same map. Does that make sense?